Deduct 1% from PayPal Request Order v2 API Request
I hope everyone is in good health.
I operate a website that connects various merchants, allowing them to receive payments from their customers. I want to implement a system where, if a merchant requests $100 from a customer, 1% of that amount is sent to my account. The remaining amount, after deducting the payment fee and the 1% commission, should be sent to the merchant's account.
For example:
Invoice Request: 100$
PayPal Fee: 3.98$
1% of 100$: 1$
Remaining Amount: 100 - 3.98 - 1 = 95.02$
So 1$ should sent to owner account
98.05$ should sent to merchant
Also, How can I add custom variables to this Order so I can get those values using below API request.
https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/1CH72974UG290335P/capture
& when the customer paid the requested amount then sandbox should be called.
I want to know how can I enable webhook, add 1% deduction, and can add custom variables.
Updated Order v2, After reading out comments.
curl --location 'https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'PayPal-Request-Id: paypal-request-id-1-sandbox' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer A11AAJl4blmlkUnocTX2KQYUdm2gz3d94isr2tL6RvemrN49bPCmI_d5EzvhdZAqOTLl-nxIycCfdaGGvHljfnhtPR2fl_CJA' \
--header 'PayPal-Partner-Attribution-ID: TEST_SP_PPCP' \
--data-raw '{
   "intent": "CAPTURE",
   "purchase_units": [
      {
         "custom_id": "customer_paying_against_invoice_using_order_v2=1_=_company_auto_id=1_=_job_auto_id=181",
         "amount": {
            "currency_code": "USD",
            "value": "100.00",
            "breakdown": {
               "item_total": {
                  "currency_code": "USD",
                  "value": "100.00"
               }
            }
         },
         "payee": {
            "email_address": "sb-xyz@business.example.com",
            "merchant_id": "L6HQNC247QXGQ"
         },
         "platform_fees": [
            {
               "amount": {
                  "currency_code": "USD",
                  "value": "1.00"
               },
               "payee": {
                  "email_address": "sb-abc@business.example.com",
                  "merchant_id": "4LZCA37NTSXH4"
               }
            }
         ],
         "items": [
            {
               "name": "Invoice 1 - Test Job",
               "description": "-",
               "unit_amount": {
                  "currency_code": "USD",
                  "value": "100.00"
               },
               "quantity": "1"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "payment_source": {
      "paypal": {
         "experience_context": {
            "payment_method_preference": "IMMEDIATE_PAYMENT_REQUIRED",
            "brand_name": "Project Name",
            "locale": "en-US",
            "landing_page": "LOGIN",
            "user_action": "PAY_NOW",
            "return_url": "https://test.com/pay.php?paypal_return_url=1",
            "cancel_url": "https://test.com/pay.php?cancel_url=1"
         }
      }
   }
}'


If you are approved as a PayPal partner/platform, which is only a possibility for some, the cleanest solution is to onboard sellers with third_party_details.features.PARTNER_FEE specified.
If a seller is onboarded that way, you will be able to specify a partner_fee amount in the v2/checkout/orders API call.

If you are not approved as a PayPal partner, options are limited and there are no good ones worth going into detail about.

Exactly. I have an approved paypal account for that, and I am onboarding sellers.
But the point is now, I want to deduct 1% as a fee so I can also get some benefit.
So what changes I have to do in my Order API so I can deduct 1% from them.
I don't want to make myself a bank like Get all the payment into my account and then send to merchant account after deducting 1%

Can you elaborate "partner_fee" with code so I can test it.

You can test it with a partner app in sandbox, but the partner fee does not go anywhere you will be able to see (it disappears in sandbox). The object is in the order create request https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#definition-order_request at purchase_units[0].payment_instruction.platform_fees

I understood this and I implemented it too. But actually, I want when I am creating an Order the payment sent to merchant account when the customer paid and 1% should be sent to owner account. Can you write a sample code for me ? Because how will I know that 1% of this amount is this. So write a sample code please.

Multiply by 0.01 and specify that amount in partner_fees

Update your answer to add the desired feature in coding form please. So I can test & approve your answer if it worked for me

I have updated my question
please check the order v2 request now.
Its not working. the whole 96.02$ send to merchant after deducting 3.98$ fee

Was the partner referrals API used to onboard the merchant with  third_party_details.features.PARTNER_FEE specified?

Yes, in the operations > third_party_details > features.

Ah you're missing an object  level in the hierarchy, purchase_units[].payment_instruction.platform_fees

can you please update your answer
so I can use that code to test.
